# Remove the top directory from a zip file without unarchiving it

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip, archive, unzip

I have a zip file that contains a top level folder when unarchived. For example, the output when unzipped looks like:

```
  top-folder/
    - file1.txt
    - file2.txt
    - another-folder/
        - file3.txt
```

I need to remove that top folder from the zip file so when the archive is unzipped it only outputs the files and lower directories. Is there a way to do this in Python without unarchiving the zip file to disk? I know I can unzip the folder then create a new zip file from the unarchived files, but I wanted to know if there any Python tricks to removing this from a zip file without writing to disk.

*I have also thought of extracting in memory and recreating that way, but the zips are 60MB compressed and I'm running this in AWS Lambda so that's not a good option.*

Comment: Have you tried handling them in a buffer? That way you do not have to write to disk.